# Flush Log4Net buffer with AdoNetAppender

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I'M using Log4Net with AdoNetAppender, and I like to flush buffer in particular time, or time period.

May be I'M not wrong, Log4Net do not provide this functionality and for that I have to create my own Appender, but I have no idea or may be I am confuse how to implement this.

Can anyone help me with this?

For flush I am suppose to use following code but it do not have time or timeout functionality.

```
    public void FlushBuffers()
    {
        ILoggerRepository rep = LogManager.GetRepository();
        foreach (IAppender appender in rep.GetAppenders())
        {
            var buffered = appender as BufferingAppenderSkeleton;
            if (buffered != null)
            {
                buffered.Flush();
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

Log4Net is implemented in Asp.Net website, and I need to flush this throw the site.

May be I can create Thread which execute code block in every 2 hours and flush the buffer.

Comment: Do you want to flush the appender, or do you want the appender to flush itself?

Comment: @stuartd I just want, whatever is there in buffer - need to write in DB.

Answer (score 6):

```
public class FlushingAdoNetAppender : AdoNetAppender
{
    private Timer flushTimer;
    private TimeSpan flushInterval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

    public FlushingAdoNetAppender()
    {
        // Enable for debugging purposes
        // LogLog.InternalDebugging = true;
    }

    public TimeSpan FlushInterval
    {
        /* 

        The interval after which the buffer will be flushed. Defaults to 5 minutes

        Example config:

        <appender name="DatabaseAppender" type="Your.Namespace.FlushingAdoNetAppender">
            <flushInterval value="00:30:00" />
        </appender>

        */

        get { return flushInterval; }
        set { flushInterval = value; }
    }

    public override void ActivateOptions()
    {
        flushTimer = new Timer(flushInterval.TotalMilliseconds);

        LogLog.Debug(GetType(), "Flush timer interval is " + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(flushTimer.Interval));

        flushTimer.Enabled = true;
        flushTimer.Elapsed += FlushLog;
        flushTimer.Start();

        base.ActivateOptions();
    }

    protected override void OnClose()
    {
        // This is called by log4net when reloading the config
        flushTimer.Stop();
        flushTimer.Dispose();
        base.OnClose(); // calls Flush()
    }

    private void FlushLog(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogLog.Debug(GetType(), "Flushing logs");
        Flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: By adding this code - In config setting I have to user FlushingAdoNetAppender instead of AdoNetAppender, and rest of all setting are as it is. Is it?

Comment: Yes, make sure you include the correct namespace in the config

Comment: And OnClose()  will call when reloading config, mean of I made change in config, unlike every time user application (web) start and stop accessing.

Comment: OnClose is overridden to dispose of the timer, otherwise you get multiple events - in every other way it behaves like the normal AdoNetAppender