# Log4net buffer size not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

im trying to enter every 100 records into the database.If i specify the buffer size as 100.It stills enters each record into the database.Is there a way where i can specify the flush interval and buffer size.So which comes first it takes that.
This is my config.

```
<log4net>
    <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="10" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, 
   System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="data source=;User ID=;Password=" />
      <commandText value="INSERT INTO Errorlog ([clientname],[username],[administration],[selectedentity],[project],[Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],
    [Message],[Exception],[browser],[ipaddress],[url],[errormessage]) VALUES (@clientname,@username,@administration,@selectedentity,@project,@log_date, @thread, @log_level, 
    @logger, @message, @exception,@browser,@ipaddress,@url,@errormessage)"/>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@clientname" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{clientname}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@username" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{username}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@administration" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{administration}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@selectedentity" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{selectedentity}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@project" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{project}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_date" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@log_level" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="50" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%level" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%message" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="2000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@browser" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{browser}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@ipaddress" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="100" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{ipaddress}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@url" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{url}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
      <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@errormessage" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="255" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
          <conversionPattern value="%property{errormessage}" />
        </layout>
      </parameter>
    </appender>


    <root>
      <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender"/>
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

Comment: If you want to specify a flush interval, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30490536/flush-log4net-buffer-with-adonetappender/30491358#30491358) for a flushing ADO Net appender

Answer (score 2):

`Buffersize` only specifies how many items shall be kept in RAM before committing them. It does not define the [Lossy](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/P_log4net_Appender_BufferingAppenderSkeleton_Lossy.htm)ness of the logger.

To define a lossy logger, you need to state that explicitly and define what can be lost:

```
<lossy value="true"/>
<evaluator type="log4net.Core.LevelEvaluator">
  <threshold value="ERROR" />
</evaluator>
```

Comment: the buffersize is working fine in console application but not a Web application.Is there any reason for that.

Comment: i want a config which uses both flush interval or buffer size to buffer it out to database to which ever comes first